# Angular Material Non-scrollable sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidenav, non-scrolling

I am working on Angular Material sidenav. How can I have a side navigation that does not scroll but remain static when scroll down the main page?

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened position="end">My drawer content</mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, your sidenav should be "fixed" :

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer class="sidenav-fixed" mode="side" opened position="end">My drawer content</mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

styles.css/sccs :

```
.sidenav-fixed {
position:fixed;
}
```